# Ansible append hostname if not FQDN

Tags: ansible

When ubuntu is installed by default, the hostname is just whatever is input into the installer.

How can I check that hostname, and append it to be a FQDN if it is not already a FQDN?

Example pseudo-yaml

```
- name: Set FQDN LAN hostname
  hostname: "{{ current_hostname }}.lan.example.com"
  when: <hostname does not end with .lan.example.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

I take that you are looking for a condition to be matched in `when:`. You can use the `ansible_fqdn` magic (fact) variable.

Example:

```yml
  - hostname:
      name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}.lan.example.com"
    when: ( 'lan.example' not in ansible_fqdn )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Module hostname is idempotent**

There is no reason to use the condition in this task. The module will either change the hostname if it is different or keep it unchanged if it is already set. For example

```yaml
  - name: Set FQDN LAN hostname
    hostname:
      name: srv.lan.example.com
```

---

**Variable ansible_hostname**

This variable always keeps the name of the host. It's possible to use it to make sure the hostname is FQDN. For example

```yaml
  - name: Set FQDN LAN hostname
    hostname:
      name: "{{ ansible_hostname }}.lan.example.com"
```